# Distriqt Local Notifications not displaying "body" property on iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework, ane

I trying to display a simple local notification on iOS but for some reason Notification.body is not being displayed. On Android everything works as expected.

This is the code for creating the notification:

```
    var notification:Notification = new Notification();
    notification.id         = int(Math.random()*100);
    notification.tickerText = "New quiz is here!";
    notification.title      = "New quiz!";
    notification.body       = quizTitle + "Take the quiz now!";
    notification.count      = 1;
    notification.iconType   = NotificationIconType.APPLICATION;
    notification.vibrate    = true;
    notification.playSound  = false;
    notification.delay      = 5;
```

And this is how it is displayed, as you can't see, there is no body:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS does not support a "body" in a notification. Generally only the app name, title/message and an action.

Regards,
Michael